# Is it possible to put this regex into one step rather than two?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove special characters and replace whitespace with hyphens and i'm doing it like this:

```js
string
  .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
  .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
```

my question is: is it possible to do this in **one** step rather than two?

Comment: be warned: you may be throwing away **alphabetic** non-ASCII characters. Like Beyoncé could become Beyonc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're replacing one selection with substitution #1 and the second selection with substitution #2, it shouldn't be possible to combine those.